# Django thousand separator in ModelForms input fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How I can add thousand separators for number input fields in a ModelForm. I am using  'load humanize' and '|intcomma' in templates to format some numbers.but How I could do that for fields in modelforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24013399)

Comment: But I've included the essential part of the answer: `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True`

Comment: USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR is a global setting, though. If you are localizing with respect to a specific form, a custom template or a localization parameter in the specific ModelForm is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you should try and handle it on the client side with JS. This was also my solution.
This is how I solved the problem:

1. create general number format JS function:

   function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
   number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+-Ee.]/g, '');
   var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
   prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
   sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
   dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
   s = '',
   toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
   var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
   return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
   };
   // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
   s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
   if (s[0].length > 3) {
   s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
   }
   if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
   s[1] = s[1] || '';
   s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
   }
   return s.join(dec);
   }

2. create thousand separator specific code:

   function thousand_sep(tagID, x_value) {
   if (x_value == "") {
   document.getElementById(tagID).value = "";
   return;
   }
   document.getElementById(tagID).value = number_format(x_value, 0, ',', ' ');
   }
3. Add the code to your ModelForm in your Django forms.py:

   class AnyForm(forms.ModelForm):

   ```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['numeric_field'].widget.attrs = {
            'oninput': "thousand_sep(this.id, this.value)",
        }
   ```

This works for me. Hope it helps. (sorry for the JS code format, it did not highlight it as code for some reason)